# Traversing through xml file

Tags: c#

I have XML like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
  <atag>
    <element1 att="value" />
    <element2 att="othervalue"/>
  </atag>
  <othertag>
    <element1 att="value" />
    <element2 att="othervalue"/>
  </othertag>
</config>
```

I want to traverse through the file and find "element1" tag and raplce it with "abc" tag.
Please help. Thank You in advance

In the same file I want to store att value in an array first then raplace the tag name to "abc" . Please help me out

Comment: You should look into either the System.Xml.XmlElement or (in my opinion) the better System.Xml.Linq.XElement. With that you can replace elements in a XML file easily and quickly. Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: [XElement.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(fileName);

foreach (var e in xml.Root.Elements().SelectMany(x => x.Elements("element1")))
{
    e.Name = "abc";
}

xml.Save(fileName);
```